# Algorithm to modify strings in a stack

Tags: c, string, algorithm

I'm tackling an issue with a stack. I have a string. Each letter activates push to stack and each `*` activates pop from the stack.

For example

```
T_I**_MA***SB*E***
```

to get the output `I_AM_BEST`.

I want to create an algorithm that finds out, if it is possible to add stars (`*`) to any of the two given strings in order to recreate another string.

For example, I got 2 strings `s1` and `s2` as input.

```
s1 = "hello"
s2 = "lle"
```

the algorithm looks at `s1` and verifies that I can pop string 2 from string 1.
So it gives me output `hell***o` from string 1.

However, I cannot create `s1` from `s2`, because I miss letters `h` and `o`.

Now my struggle was to find efficient way to do all comparisons, since I need to check all the letters and order.

If anyone would like to help me I would be really grateful. Also feel free to ask me for additional information.

[Here](https://codeshare.io/VqK1s) is my code so far.

EDIT: 
Thanks to everyone for some really nice ideas, they get me going and I have finally cracked it using this recursion. Just a dirty working edition. Seems like it's working so far :)

```
char global[40];

void rec(char s1[], char s2[], int b, int l, int count, int cur_count)
{
    if(l >= strlen(s2) || b > strlen(s1))
        return;

    if(cur_count >= count) {
        global[strlen(global)] = s2[l];
        count++;
    }

    if(s1[b] == s2[l])
    {
        global[strlen(global)] = '*';
        rec(s1,s2,++b,0,count,0);
    }
    else {
        rec(s1,s2,b,++l,count,++cur_count);
    }

}


void findString()
{
    char s1[] = "123456";
    char s2[] = "531246";

    rec(s1,s2,0,0,0,0);
    int i = 0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(global);i++)
        printf("%c",global[i]);

}
```

Comment: post the code here, and just the most important parts please!

Comment: You should not post code in an external link, but include it in your question. In this case, however, you also should make sure it's a [mcve]. Try to minimize the problem code to a single function, with clearly defined inputs and outputs.

Comment: @RadLexus OP's problem is that he doesn't actually have an algorithm, let alone any code implementing it,

Answer (score 2):

I would try this approach:

Use a string to represent the stack - call it `st`

So the basic idea is:

```
while(s1 not empty)
{
    if (st[0] == s2[0])
    {
        // result += '*'
        // pop 
        // remove s2[0]
    }
    else if if (s1[0] == s2[0])
    {
        // result += s1[0] + '*'
        // push
        // pop
        // remove s1[0]
        // remove s2[0]
    }
    else
    {
        // result += s1[0]
        // push
        // remove s1[0]
     }
}
```

The approach would work like:

```
// Initialization
st = ""         // stack - push and pop is done on st[0]
s1 = "hello"
s2 = "lle"
result = ""

// Stack empty -> do nothing
// s1[0] != s2[0] -> just push s1[0] and remove it from s1
st = "h"
s1 = "ello"
s2 = "lle"
result = "h"

// st[0] != s2[0] -> do nothing
// s1[0] != s2[0] -> just push s1[0] and remove it from s1
st = "eh"
s1 = "llo"
s2 = "lle"
result = "he"

// st[0] != s2[0] -> do nothing
// s1[0] == s2[0] -> push and pop s1[0] and remove it from s1 and remove s2[0] 
st = "eh"
s1 = "lo"
s2 = "le"
result = "hel*"

// st[0] != s2[0] -> do nothing
// s1[0] == s2[0] -> push and pop s1[0] and remove it from s1 and remove s2[0] 
st = "eh"
s1 = "o"
s2 = "e"
result = "hel*l*"

// st[0] == s2[0] -> pop and remove s2[0]
st = "h"
s1 = "o"
s2 = ""
result = "hel*l**"

// s2 empty -> just push the rest of s1
st = "oh"
s1 = ""
s2 = ""
result = "hel*l**o"
```

Notice that I got the string `"hel*l**o` which differs from your example (i.e. `hell***o`) but it still generates the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to do. Char pointer will be most helpful here and easy to implement. 
First of all you find out which string is bigger and which one is smaller. 
Now we have to compare if smaller string contains in bugger or not . Now reverse your smaller string using `strrev(char pointer)`  and store it in another char pointer .
You can use:

```
   strncmp(bigger string(char pointer),smaller string(char pointer),size of smaller string);
```

Now check with simple as well as reversed smaller string. This function return `0` if match found.
Now you remove first character from bigger string and then do the same process. Then remove again first until length of bigger string be less than smaller string.
And if two strings are of equal length then simply use `strcmp(string1,string2);` this also returns `0` if match found.

Example of storing string in character pointer:

```
Char *str= "string\0";
```

If you do `str++` then now it'll print "tring" .
This way you can remover first character from the string.

Comment: You realise that if s1 = `ABC` and s2=`BCA`, it's possible (`AB*C**`) but if s2=`CAB` it's impossible...?

Comment: Ya for that case you have to do cyclic shift .

Comment: How does your algorithm cope with the example of getting I_AM_BEST out of T_I_MASBE?

Comment: No I gave him simple solution for checking two string if one contains in another or not. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If I was tackling this problem then I would not use the stack to check if it was possible pop `s2` from `s1`. If you have `s2` and `s1` already defined in memory then you can work through them character by character as arrays.

There are probably many ways to solve this, but I would write a recursive function that would check to see if each character of `s2` could be generated by adding stars to `s1`.

For each character of `s2` I would look through `s1` to see if there is a match so that a character could be 'popped from the stack' for the first character of `s2` and then see if the next character (previous character in string) could be popped from the stack -- if it could not then would continue looking through `s1` for the next character etc. until either running out of `s1` characters to sort through or `s2` characters to match.